# Craft Commerce 4 - customer phone number/address?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, commerce4

i am using Craft Commerce 4 and cannot get my head around how to add a phone number to a customers address at Checkout. I have a Commerce 3 site but the code does not work. I can see how to add a custom field to the Settings > User Settings > Address in admin but is there no longer a native phone field for an address?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is here, since you already mentioned the solution. Addresses in Craft 4 have a field layout, so you can add any fields you want to them. There are some native properties you can add (`organization`, `fullName`, etc), but a phone number isn't one of them. To add a phone number to every address, first create a custom field (either a text field or a [phone number field](https://plugins.craftcms.com/phone-number)). Then go to *Settings* -> *Users* -> *Address Fields* and add the phone number to the field layout.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i was just trying to figure out if i was missing something and if a custom field was now the proper way of doing it - thank you for confirming that - much appreciated

Comment: @MalcolmMaclean Absolutely, it's always good to use what's available! If your question is solved, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!